# Ambisonics makes weird beeps

Tags: unity-game-engine, fmod, resonance-audio

A.

First of all, I'm using FMOD v. 1.10.02 w/ Resonance Audio.

When using the Soundfield in FMOD I get weird beeps and squeaky noises when rotating my HMD. I've put the R.A. Soundfield effect on the master of an event and the Resonance Audio Listener on the Group master of my ambisonics.

This makes the Soundfield effect unusable and therefor - no ambisonics for me :( Is this only happening for me?

Best regards,
Frederik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I found out that the Soundfield behaves weird when the audiofile has a lot of low frequencies, removing some of them with an eq did the trick and the small beeps is now gone. Instead of removing this post, I'll leave it here - maybe this can be helpful for others ;)